# Liquibase script to change BLOB data to CLOB in oracle

Tags: oracle, blob, liquibase, clob

I need to change one BLOB column type into CLOB so it will store data in json form. But I need to migrate all existing data to new format. Is there a way in liquibase to convert all stored BLOBs into CLOB.
Any links/ reference would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

It will help u

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION blob_to_clob (blob_in IN BLOB)
RETURN CLOB
AS
     v_clob    CLOB;
     v_varchar VARCHAR2(32767);
     v_start      PLS_INTEGER := 1;
     v_buffer  PLS_INTEGER := 32767;
BEGIN
     DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(v_clob, TRUE);

     FOR i IN 1..CEIL(DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(blob_in) / v_buffer)
     LOOP

        v_varchar := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(blob_in, v_buffer, v_start));

           DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(v_clob, LENGTH(v_varchar), v_varchar);

          v_start := v_start + v_buffer;
     END LOOP;

   RETURN v_clob;

END blob_to_clob;
/
```

https://community.oracle.com/thread/206993